# VHDL what does this mean? a <= a (6 downto 0) & '0'

Tags: vhdl

```
signal a : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');

a <= a (6 downto 0) & '0';
```

So I understand that `a` is a signal that is 8 bits and all of those bits are 0. Is the next line assigning bits 6 down to 0 to be zero again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the equivalent syntax would help understand:

```
a(7 downto 0) <= a(6 downto 0) & '0';
```

So `a(7)` gets the value of `a(6)`, `a(6)` the value of `a(5)`, ... and `a(0)` is `'0'`.

This code describe a shift register (assuming the statement is enclosed in a synchronous process, which should be to prevent combinational loop) where values are shifted left every cycle.

In VHDL, `&` is the concatenation operator. So `"0101" & "1010"` is equal to `"01011010"`. In your example, the 7 LSBs are concatenated to a logical zero to form a new shifted 8 bits vector.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very short definition for shifting the bits to the left by replacing rightmost bit with '0'.